# Creating vectors with while loops Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, vector

In this code, I am trying to get the vector to print replace each element with the number 3 until I reach the first number less than 50.

```
 z=[4 3 2 5 7 9 0 64 34 49];
 counter=1;

 while counter<length(z)
     if z(counter) >0 && z(counter) < 50
          z(counter)=3;

     end
     counter=counter+1;
 end
 z
```

Instead of z(counter)=3  ....Why cant I replace it with z=[z 3]?
Why can I not replace the fifth line of the code with z=[z 3] .  Matlab wont let me do it
and I am confused about the logic.

Comment: Not really clear what you mean by `z(counter=3)` ... that does not appear in your code. Do you mean `z(counter)=3`?

Comment: You say you want to replace elements "until you reach your first number less than fifty" but that is not what your code does. Also your first number (i.e. 4) is less than fifty so what you're describing would do nothing to your example data. Is this correct? Or did you describe it incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the same thing as in your code with

```
 z(z<50 & z>0)=3;
```

The statement `z=[z 3]` appends the value 3 to vector `z`, which doesn't seem to be what you want. Instead `z(counter)=3` *substitutes* the current element indexed by `counter` with `3`.

Comment: z(counter)=3 is on the fifth line.  I wanted to know why I cant replace it with z=[z 3].  I am confused as to why when I used z=[z 3] , matlab is not letting me do it.